# Behind the scene allocation of memory on heap using malloc

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, dynamic-memory-allocation, memory-alignment

if a process request 1-24 bytes on heap why 32 bytes difference ?

if a process request 25-40 bytes on heap why 48 bytes difference ?

if a process request 41-56 bytes on heap why 64 bytes difference ?

Initial 8bytes is used to hold the length of the allocated memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main()
{

  int size=41;
  char* c = (char*) malloc(size);//initial 8bytes used for length
  char* d = (char*) malloc(size);
  printf("a = %p\nb = %p\n difference is %d\n",c,d,d-c);
  free(c);
  free(d);

}
```

Comment: What makes you think `malloc` is allocating the 32, 48, or 64 bytes you describe? Are you looking at the differences between the pointers it returns? If two pointers differ by 32 bytes, that does not mean there are 32 bytes you can use in the allocation between them. Likely `malloc` has put, say, eight bytes of its own data in there somewhere to help it know about that block of memory when you pass it to `free`.

Comment: That information should be in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually the function malloc is  implemented such a way that it returns a chunk of memory multiple by the paragraph size equal to 16 bytes (this value can be equal to the value of `alignof(max_align_t)`). That is the allocated memory must be aligned for any allocated object.

Comment: why is it like that so ? what could be the reason for  paragraph size == 16 bytes only ?

Comment: @mohammedyaqub For example sizeof( long double ) is equal to 16. The function malloc does not know for an object of which  type the memory is allocated. Its argument is a value of the type size_t. But it shall guarantee the alignment. So it uses the most strict alignment.